# Ruby - elegantly flatten an array but don't ignore empty sub-arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten, sub-array

Using `.flatten` is a handy little trick to take an array of sub-arrays and turn it into a single array.
For example: `[[1,3],2,[5,8]].flatten` => `[1,3,2,5,8]`
You can even include nil `[1,[2,nil],3].flatten` will result in `[1,2,nil,3]`.

This kind of method is very useful when nesting a `.map` method, but how would you account for an empty sub-array? For example: `[1,[2,3],[],4].flatten` would return `[1,2,3,4]`... but what if I need to keep track of the empty sub array maybe turn the result into `[1,2,3,0,4]` or `[1,2,3,nil,4]`

Is there any elegant way to do this? Or would I need to write some method to iterate through each individual sub-array and check it one by one?

Comment: Do you need to check for nested empty arrays, ie `[1, [2, 3, []], 4]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to recursively check nested sub-arrays:

```
[1,[2,3],[],4].map { |a| a == [] ? nil : a }.flatten
```

Comment: This is a bit cleaner than what i had. I changed a == [] to a.any? but similar concept... For some reason I always overlook putting logic into my .map blocks.

Comment: @jkessluk won't a.any? choke on items which aren't arrays?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using this in a helper method where I've already ensured that the item passed through is an array. Otherwise, yes. You're correct.

Answer (score 2):

First map the empty arrays into `nil`s, then flatten

```
[1,2,[1,2,3],[]].map{|x| if x.is_a? Array and x.empty? then nil else x end}.flatten
```